# Automatically Passing Certian values in BackBone Model Ajax Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone js to create an app like service. Every application has a user_id and an application_id that has been set. Each time that backbone calls a fetch(), save(), or any other RESTful/ajax function, I want the user_id and the application_id to automatically be passed with the models data.

I know I am going to have to extend the backbone model, and then make sure all my models extend from this model, but what do I modify and how do I call the parent model?

Psuedo Example (not quite sure)

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    save : function(data) {
        data.application_id = 3;
        data.user_id = 5;
        parent.save(data);
}
});

Scores = MyModel.extend({
      default : {
      score : 0
}
});

//This should automatically grab the application id and user id
scores = new Scores();
scores.set('score', 5);
score.save()
```

How do I correctly accomplish this? And by accomplish I mean an single point in the code that will work for save(), fetch() and destroy() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about modifying your Backbone sync? If you're sure you want to pass the `user_id` and `application_id` with EVERY model on `save() fetch() and destroy()` then you could do something like this I believe...

```
/* alias away the sync method */
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;

/* new Backbone.sync method */
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {

    // For example purpose, this will only run on POST, PUT, and DELETE requests
    // If you want you can also set it for method == 'read' for your fetch()

    if (method == 'create' || method == 'update' || method == 'delete') {
        model.set('user_id', userID);
        model.set('application_id', appID);
    }

    /* proxy the call to the old sync method */
    return Backbone._sync(method, model, options);
};
```

I do something like this for my CSRF token check to prevent cross site registration forgeries. Except instead of manipulating the model, I make sure all my POST, PUT, and DELETE requests have a special X-CSRF header with my unique token.

Comment: The exact answer I was looking for! Works for collections also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your values (appid and userid) are pre-determined, you can do this in the `initialize` method of your model

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  this.set('application_id', appID);
  this.set('user_id', userID);
});
```

These values are now part of your model and therefore part of every CRUD operation.